# Why did I get error by using strchr() in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, strchr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string a="asdasd";
    if(!strchr(a,'a')) cout<<"yes";
    return 0;
}
```

I just began to learn C++ programming and I don't know why I got error in this line

```
if(!strchr(a,'a')) cout<<"yes";
```

But if I tried to code it like this, it would run very well.

```
if(!strchr("asdasd",'a')) cout<<"yes";
```

I know it is a stupid question but I really don't know why.. sorry..

Comment: try `if(!strchr(a.c_str(),'a'))` instead

Comment: use `a.find()` instead of `strchr`

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `strchr`?

Comment: You should always show us the *exact* error you get.  Also, you should stop mucking about with C-style strings and their related functions in a C++ program.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you guys, because I saw others use strchr so I thought it also worked for C++.

Comment: `strchr` _can_ be used in C++ but it's not idiomatic and typically frowned upon. In C++ there are much better ways of dealing with strings as you are now finding out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library function `strchr` is for use with C-style strings, not the C++ `string` type.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Sorry for my stupid question again..

Answer (score 2):

When using `std::string`, the closest equivalent of `strchr` is `find`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string a="asdasd";
    if(a.find('a') != std::string::npos) std::cout<<"yes";
}
```